# PHP Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 2: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected in

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm facing below issues while using SimpleXMLElement

> PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 2: parser
>   error : AttValue: " or ' expected in
>
> PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():  in
>
> PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():            ^ in
>
> PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 2: parser
>   error : attributes construct error in
>
> PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 2: parser
>   error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 2

I've tried like these but no luck.

> $remove = file_get_contents(stripslashes("URL"));
>
> $remove = preg_replace("/[\d\D]*?</provision>/",
>   "", $remove);
>
> $remove = str_replace(array("&", "&"), array("&", "&"),
>   $remove);
>
> $xml = simplexml_load_string($remove);

code is below

```
$response = $this->performRequest ( $search, 'xml' );
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement ( $response ); 
$status = ( int ) $xml->Response->Status->code;
```

> $xml = new SimpleXMLElement ( $response ); -- in this line I'm facing
>   those issues.

assist me to resolve this

I've printed the $response.that shows the element like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/maps/geo</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: Can you show the element (or the XML itself) source which is causing the problem?

Comment: @NigelRen added element above. please take a look